# Hydrostatic force from a fluid with varying density

Tags: fluid-statics

How do I solve for the hydrostatic force acting on a vertical surface from a fluid with linearly varying density?

A. $dF = \rho g h\cdot dA$ and integrate to solve F

or

B. $dP = \rho g dh$ and integrate to solve for P and substitute P to...
   $dF = P\cdot dA$ and integrate for F

where $F =$ Force, $\rho =$ density, $g = 9.81 m/s^2$, $h =$ height, $A =$ area, $P =$ pressure.

I was expecting to arrive with the same answer from the two methods but apparently, upon solving, I was wrong. I am now more inclined to solution B, because my colleagues said that the equation in solution A is only applicable to constant density but I cannot confirm it from the textbooks that I have researched. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the density is a function of pressure and the pressure is varying with height, the density must be varying with height also.  So, which value of the density do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a height $h$ for an infinitesimal change in height $dh$ the change in pressure $dP$ is given by $dP= g \rho(h) dh$ where $\rho(h)$ is the density of the fluid at height $h$.
To find the change in pressure you now need to integrate and then using $PA$ where $P$ is the pressure acting on $A$ you can find the force.

Your method **A** assumes a constant density for the fluid.